# How can i animate text word by word in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, animation, text

Hello every I'm new in iPhone development I want to animate text word by for in `UITextView` if any one can please tell me from very basics I'll be very thankful to you all !!

Comment: Care to tell us more about how you would like "animate" your text? Tell us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont be animated really but you could break the text you want to display into words with

NSArray *wordsToDisplay = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

then run a timer and everytime the timer fires, add another word to the text in the textview, invalidating the timer once all the words are displayed

Comment: Thank you wattson but i've tried this breaking up thing for several times but non of the time i successfully achieved this ... if u can help through a detailed example i'll be very thankful to you !